# catalogProductList - adding 'nin' filters

Tags: api, soap-api-v2

I cannot find any documentation (other than the WSDL itself) that provides a working example of how to filter a SOAP API_v2 `catalogProductList`.

I have a list of skus and I want to filter the list with `nin` (not in) so that the response gives me all products *other* than what I have in my skus.

```
$skus = array('1','2','3');
$filter = array(
    'sku' => array('nin' => $skus)
)
$productList = $client->catalogProductList($session, $filter);

// Returns all products in the store instead of filtered list.
Zend_Debug::dump($productList);
```

I have also see the `$filter` being built with `complex_filters` that uses a different array structure, but I don't understand what the difference is.

**How do I simply filter an API product list using the `nin` method?**

---

EDIT

Trying with `complex_filters`, using 'eq' works, but not 'nin':

```
// this returns a single product with sku 12345
$filter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array('key' => 'sku', 'value' => array('key' => 'eq', 'value' => '12345'))
    )
);

// This results in an error - "Notice: Array to string conversion  in ..."
$filter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array('key' => 'sku', 'value' => array('key' => 'nin', 'value' => array('12345', '67890'))
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API V2 queries use a "complex filter" for advanced queries.  Their syntax is a bit different.  Here's a complex filter query for your sample:

```
$filter = array(
  array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'sku',
        'value' => array('key' => 'nin', 'value' => '1,2,3')
      )
    )
  )
);

$productList = $client->catalogProductList($session, $filter);
```

More query samples are available on the [catalogProduct API Doc page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.list.html)

Comment: As I just edited and figured out, the `value` needs to be a comma separated string not an array. Thanks for the documentation Magento!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

`array('nin'=>$skus)` instead of `array('nin',$skus)`

Then it should work!

Comment: That's just a typo in my question.